# React component in component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do a `<DropdownLink />` inside a `<BootstrapDropdown />` in my code, but I dunno how to.

I've tried to solve the problem with React documentation, but I didn't find anything.

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../scss/app.scss';
import BootstrapDropdown from './helpers/bootstrapDropdown';
import DropdownLink from './helpers/dropdownLink';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BootstrapDropdown name={"Dropdown"}>
        <DropdownLink name={"Strona główna"} href={"/"} />
      </BootstrapDropdown>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

dropdownLink.js

```js
import React from 'react';

class DropdownLink extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <a className="dropdown-item" href={this.props.href}>{this.props.name}</a>
  }
}

export default DropdownLink;
```

bootstrapDropdown.js

```js
import React from 'react';

class BootstrapDropdown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="dropdown">
      <button className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {this.props.name}
      </button>
      <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}

export default BootstrapDropdown;
```

I want to show a `<DropdownLink />` inside a `<div className="dropdown-menu"></div>` in `<BootstrapDropdown />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell where to render the children:

```
import React from 'react';

class BootstrapDropdown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="dropdown">
      <button className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {this.props.name}
      </button>
      <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          {this.props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}

export default BootstrapDropdown;
```

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I will send an image